# How can I hold off a 2 player 7pool rush?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

How can I hold off the initial 2 player 7Pool rush as a Zerg?  I usually go a 10Pool build when I see two Randoms or a Zerg and a Random matchup.  I'm mostly referring to scenarios in 3's games.

What sort of building placement is favorable?

Also, how do I effectively micro with my Drones?  I usually manage to kill only 1 or 2 Zerglings with my Drone micro.  I think I'm doing something wrong, like selecting too many drones at once.

Comment: You might want to split these up into two different questions. :)

Comment: Some advice here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/defending-double-6-pool-in-2v2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get double rushed in a 2v2 or 3v3 game, you will likely die or be *severely* crippled, and there's nothing that can be done about it.  Your job in this case is to [**die as slowly as possible.**](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/4330673/)

If both your opponents have rushed quickly enough to do that much damage that early, their economies will be very poor, and your ally should use the time they spent beating on you to 
get some tech and a strong economy.

Answer (score 1):

I've outlined basic strategy for drone handling in case of a 2 players zergling rush attack  [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/defending-double-6-pool-in-2v2/6404#6404)